# Pagination w/ query data in url for initial search submission not holding but all subsequent pages have url params

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

How can I get the paramaters passed to the url on the first submission?

All subsequent pagination requests (such as when I hit Next>>) display the proper url parameters like (/35/0/...):

```
.../Plans/search/35/0/0/0/97378/page:2
```

But on the first search results page, the parameters are not passed (but the results are correct), so the url looks like this:

```
.../Plans/search/
```

So when I try to do a sort on the first page:

```
<?php $this->Paginator->sort('Sort by Monthly Cost','monthly_cost');?>
```

The results are cleared because no parameters are present. But every subsequent page (starting at page:2) the sort works fine because the params are in the url.

I need to know how to pass the params to the url on the initial search.

I've been trying variations of this in the view:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

But I can't get them to pass..

Comment: And this is how I am "catching" the parameters on the pagination after the first page: $paginator->options = array('url'=>$searchdetails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

In my view, I had an instance of:

options = array('url'=>$searchdetails); ?>

below my paginator counter near the page footer.

I took the same:

options = array('url'=>$searchdetails); ?>

And placed it in the header of my view, and it solved the issue.

It appears the vars were not being saved until I initiated the pagination by clicking Next>>, so adding it at the header saves the immediately on the first search.

So I removed the footer instance, and now only have:

options = array('url'=>$searchdetails); ?>

At the header of the page, and it carries all values to the url as expected : )